# How to populate Menus dynamically in VB.net windows application from Sql server

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am working on a window based application in vb.net and want to populate the menu from sql server based on role and rights provided to user .
please suggest me that how to populate menus in vb.net from sql server.

Comment: What kind of menus do you want to populate?

Comment: Its drop down menu , but should be handled in database and appears based on users role in vb.net windows based application

Answer (score 0):

You just create dynamic menu in runtime

```
    private void MenuLoad()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem Menu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        Menu1.Text = "sometext";
        Menu1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(Menu1_CheckedChanged);          

    }

    void Menu1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: But I want that menu comes from database and appears based on users role and right